# Create portable pgaudit extension for windows

Tags: postgresql

How shall i create and manage portable pgaudit extension for windows? I couldn't install with makefile.
This is the error below:
D:\pgxs.mk:85: D:/Windows/: Permission denied
D:\pgxs.mk:85: Files/PostgreSQL/12/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/Makefile.global: No such file or directory
D:\pgxs.mk:224: /src/Makefile.shlib: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/src/Makefile.shlib'.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but on Windows it is recommended to build this extension the following way according to https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit/issues/66

> I have found that Postgres extensions on Windows are very sensitive to
>   exactly how they are built. I would try to build the extension by
>   dropping the pgaudit source code directory into a full Postgres source
>   code tree under "contrib", and then build the entire thing following
>   the docs for a Windows source build. Then take the resulting
>   pgaudit.dll and use that.